# How to Change Background Image Attribute in JS

Tags: javascript, css, image

I'm currently attempting to change an attribute of a JS variable from url("../images/video.png") (how it was declared in the CSS) to url("../images/pause.png") via this line of code:

fullscreenPlayPauseButton.style.backgroundImage = "url("../images/pause.png")";

The mouse over of the image is showing the image and both images are in the folder. However, once this line of code is executed, the image that originally showed up (the video.png) turns grey. The error I'm getting in console is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." on the line where that code is. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please consider preparing a Stack Snippet (click the icon that looks like a page with angle brackets in the question editor) or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with a [mcve]. Otherwise, it's very difficult for us to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two doublequotes in one line. You have to escape them or use single quotes:

```
fullscreenPlayPauseButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/pause.png')";
```

or

```
fullscreenPlayPauseButton.style.backgroundImage = "url(\"../images/pause.png\")";
```

Both should work.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the property like this:

```
fullscreenPlayPauseButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/pause.png')";
```